# Select by length of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select the longest phrase that has `points>0` but being contained in a phrase which has `points=0`, if you look at the demo than the rows in output would be number 3 and 6:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e954f/1/0

many thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  (2) A SQL Fiddle is really good -- to augment the information in a question.  You should provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Comment: Are you sure it's 3 and 6? The 7th row has more characters and points than the 6th.

Comment: Tomasz Kasperczyk yes but line 6 is contained in a longer length than line 7, it has a longer matching

Comment: You want the longest phrase, but you want two records in output. This is impossible. How do you determine groups of phrases to compare with and get longest for each group?

Comment: Kamil Gosciminski my indication are the rows with 0 points, now I have to find the phrase with points >0  with the longest match contained, I know I might not explaining myself the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner join comparing the phrases with a `LIKE` to get only the ones contained in another phrase. Filter for the point in a `WHERE` clause. Then get the `rank()` partitioned by the phrase from the joined instance and ordered by the length descending. In an outer `SELECT` only get the ones with a rank of one.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.phrase,
       x.points
       FROM (SELECT w1.id,
                    w1.phrase,
                    w1.points,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY w2.phrase
                                 ORDER BY len(w1.phrase) DESC) r
                    FROM words w1
                         INNER JOIN words w2
                                    ON w2.phrase LIKE concat(w1.phrase, '%')
                    WHERE w2.points = 0
                          AND w1.points > 0) x
       WHERE x.r = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e954f/49)

---

Edit:

To include the other phrase:

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.phrase,
       x.other_phrase,
       x.points
       FROM (SELECT w1.id,
                    w1.phrase,
                    w2.phrase other_phrase,
                    w1.points,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY w2.phrase
                                 ORDER BY len(w1.phrase) DESC) r
                    FROM words w1
                         INNER JOIN words w2
                                    ON w2.phrase LIKE concat(w1.phrase, '%')
                    WHERE w2.points = 0
                          AND w1.points > 0) x
       WHERE x.r = 1;
```

Comment: I spend so much time working with MySQL 5.x I forget most SQL supports `RANK`. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sticky bit

Comment: I am using this solution though it is missing a column of the matching phrase with the 0 points, how could I add such column? thank for your help http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24f134/4/0

Comment: @refaelo1979: Simply add it to the list. See the edit.

Comment: @sticky bit  I'm grateful

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to find all phrases with positive points which are a substring of a phrase with 0 points. Then you can find the maximum length of the substrings associated with each 0 point phrase, and `JOIN` that back to the CTE to get the phrase that matches that condition:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT w1.*, w2.id AS w2_id
FROM words w1
JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM words
      WHERE points = 0) w2 ON w1.phrase = LEFT(w2.phrase, LEN(w1.phrase))
WHERE w1.points > 0
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.phrase, points
FROM cte
JOIN (SELECT w2_id, MAX(LEN(phrase)) AS max_len
      FROM cte
      GROUP BY w2_id) cte_max ON cte_max.w2_id = cte.w2_id AND cte_max.max_len = LEN(cte.phrase)
```

Output:

```
id  phrase              points
3   tool box online     1
6   stone road          1
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e954f/44)

Comment: Very appreciated Nick

Answer (score 0):

You will get from max to min length of phrase where `points>0`

```
SELECT *, LEN(phrase) AS Lenght FROM words where points>0 ORDER BY LEN(phrase) DESC
```

And if you want the longest phrase

```
 SELECT TOP 1 *, LEN(phrase) AS Lenght FROM words where points>0 ORDER BY LEN(phrase) DESC
```